# VBA First visible cell selection above header in after filtering

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I am in need of help with VBA code.I am pretty new to VBA and can't find a solution to a problem with selecting first visible cell, above the header, in a column, after filtering. I want to select this cell to set its value to "x" and then i need to put "x" for every filtered row in my table.
Mabye you know the way to make it easier by selecting visible cells in column BK and put "x" in them? This column has only blank cells.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
Sub Filter_and_insert()
'
' Filter_and_insert Makro
'

 'Select an active worksheet

    Sheets("DANE PIPELINE 29.10").Select

 ' First filter I use for data

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$BQ$4773").AutoFilter Field:=40, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "C.O.R.", "Contract", "Positive Quote", "Quote", "Selling"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues

 ' Second filter I use for data

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$BQ$4773").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:= _
        "Not assigned"

 ' Here I need to select first visible cell above header after filtering and set its 
 ' value to  "x".
 ' Range ("BK36") is only for this current data and it will be different for 
 ' other data so thats why I need to find first visible cell.

    Range("BK36").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "x"

  ' Here I am selecting all filtered cells in a row and fill them with "x"

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -20).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown

   ' Reset filters

            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=40
            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=25


End Sub
```

Thanks very much for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will place an **"x"** in each visible cell in column **BK**

```
Sub MarkX()
    Dim rX As Range
    Set rX = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("BK:BK")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rX.Value = "x"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very much for response. It worked for me. Had to modify it a bit and then I come to an idea and wrote this: "Range([BK4], Cells(Rows.Count, "BK")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select". you need to use first hidden cell above header, BK4 in my case. Thank you for Your help again.